# How to get the text after the tag

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

How to get the text after the tag is found

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import lxml.html

html = """
<b>Point1:</b> Text1 <br>
<b>Point2:</b> Text2 <br>
...
<b>PointN:</b> TextN
<b>PointN+1:</b> TextN+1<br>
"""
dom = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
el = dom.xpath('//b[text()="PointN:"]')
print el
```

tag el with the text PointN found out how to get text TextN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `TextN` follows the `<b>` that you already found, you can use the XPath `following` axis:

```
dom.xpath('//b[text() = "PointN:"]/following::node()')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is:

```
el = dom.xpath('//b[text()="PointN:"]')[0]
print el.tail
```